# How to set the route_table_id

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

main.tf

```
  private_nat_cidrs = {
    test-prod-ec2-1 = {
      subnet = "10.1.0.0/23"
      name   = "test-prod-ec2-1"
      az     = "ap-northeast-1a"
    }
    test-prod-ec2-2 = {
      subnet = "10.1.2.0/23"
      name   = "test-prod-ec2-2"
      az     = "ap-northeast-1c"
    }
    test-prod-ec2-3 = {
      subnet = "10.1.4.0/23"
      name   = "test-prod-ec2-3"
      az     = "ap-northeast-1d"
    }
  }
```

subnet.tf

```
/**
 * private subnet(NAT)
 */
resource "aws_subnet" "nat" {
  for_each = var.private_nat_cidrs

  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.test.id
  availability_zone       = lookup(each.value, "az")
  cidr_block              = lookup(each.value, "subnet")
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
      Name = format("%s_%s", var.env_prefix, lookup(each.value, "name"))
    }
  )

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

nat.tf

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "private" {
  for_each = var.public_subnet_cidrs

  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_gateway.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public[each.key].id

  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
      Name = format("%s_%s_%s", var.env_prefix, var.env_name, "nat-gateway")
    }
  )

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

route_table.tf

```
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  for_each = aws_nat_gateway.private

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dandori.id

  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
      Name = format("%s_%s", var.env_prefix, var.env_name)
    }
  )

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = each.value["id"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  for_each = aws_subnet.nat

  subnet_id      = each.value["id"]
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private[each.key].id

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

**【Error】**

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../modules/aws/vpc/route_table.tf line 69, in resource "aws_route_table_association" "private":
│   69:   route_table_id = aws_route_table.private[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_route_table.private is object with 1 attribute "test-prod-nat"
│     │ each.key is "test-prod-ec2-1"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../modules/aws/vpc/route_table.tf line 69, in resource "aws_route_table_association" "private":
│   69:   route_table_id = aws_route_table.private[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_route_table.private is object with 1 attribute "test-prod-nat"
│     │ each.key is "test-prod-ec2-2"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../modules/aws/vpc/route_table.tf line 69, in resource "aws_route_table_association" "private":
│   69:   route_table_id = aws_route_table.private[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_route_table.private is object with 1 attribute "test-prod-nat"
│     │ each.key is "test-prod-ec2-3"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

I want to set the route_table_id to aws_route_table.private.id, but I don't know how to set it.
I've set the aws_route_table.private.id, but I can't set the aws_route_table.private.id directly because I'm looping through for_each.

I've tried everything, but I can't solve it.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: You are iterating over this `for_each = aws_nat_gateway.private` in `resource "aws_route_table" "private"` which means that resource will have keys provided by `aws_nat_gateway.private`. You are then trying to access `aws_route_table.private[each.key].id` for keys which do not exist as you are referencing another variable in `for_each =  aws_subnet.nat`. In short, you would have to make your keys the same if iterating the way you are now.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
If possible, I would appreciate it if you could provide a sample of how I can change the current settings.